Unir tablas, en caso de que el registro no tenga coincidencia en esa ,hacer join con la misma tabla pero con el valor mas actual!
En contexto general estoy iniciando en un projecto de facturacion en el cual se deben facturar boletos que fueron comprados en una moneda distinta al dolar, en dicho caso se hace una conversion de monedas.
Tengo problemas al momento de unir la tabla de ventas con la tabla de conversion, ya que si  no existe el registro que coincida en fecha de compra en dicha tabla lo excluye dejando fuera boletos necesarios y lo que necesito es: si existe,tomar el valor de esa moneda que coincida con fecha de compra (año,mes y dia), si no existe hacer join con la misma tabla pero obtener el ultimo valor para esa moneda sin importar su fecha de compra
P.D: La tabla de conversion se actualiza diariamente, por ende si se compro un boleto el 2024-05-01 en la tabla de conversion debe coincidir con año, mes y dia, por ejemplo:



year
month
day
currency
currency_value




2024
5
1
MXN
0.3565



La estructura de las tablas es la siguiente
TABLA DE BOLETOS: SALES



id_
fecha_compra
moneda
tarifa_base
impuesto




1
2024-05-01
MXN
15000
500


2
2024-05-01
MXN
15000
500


3
2024-05-02
MXN
15000
500


4
2024-05-02
MXN
15000
500


5
2024-05-03
MXN
15000
500


6
2024-05-03
MXN
15000
500



TABLA DE CONVERSION DE MONEDAS: CURRENT_CURRENCY



year
month
day
currency
currency_value




2024
5
1
MXN
0.3565


2024
5
3
MXN
0.3789


2024
5
4
MXN
0.3821


2024
5
5
MXN
0.3269


2024
12
2
MXN
0.3269


2023
5
6
MXN
0.3269



Esta es la consulta que estoy probando de momento:
SELECT S.*
FROM SALES S
INNER JOIN CURRENT_CURRENCY C
ON EXTRACT(YEAR FROM S.fecha_compra) = C.YEAR
   AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM S.fecha_compra) = C.MONTH
   AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM S.fecha_compra) = C.DAY
   AND S.MONEDA = C.CURRENCY

y esto solo me trae los siguientes registros:



id_
fecha_compra
moneda
tarifa_base
impuesto




1
2024-05-01
MXN
15000
500


2
2024-05-01
MXN
15000
500


5
2024-05-03
MXN
15000
500


6
2024-05-03
MXN
15000
500



excluyendo lo siguiente ya que no existe un registro coincidente con el dia (2) en el mes (5)



id_
fecha_compra
moneda
tarifa_base
impuesto




3
2024-05-02
MXN
15000
500


4
2024-05-02
MXN
15000
500



En ese escenario lo que deberia hacer es otro join pero seleccionando el valor de la moneda (MXN) mas actual (|2024|5|5|MXN|0.3269|)
Es aqui donde no logro sacar el query y esto lo que he probado de momento, pero el group by no funciona como deberia:
SELECT S.*
      , CASE
            WHEN C.currency_value IS NULL 
                THEN S.tarifa_base * DT.currency_value
            ELSE S.tarifa_base * C.currency_value
        END as tarifa_base_usd
FROM SALES S
LEFT JOIN CURRENT_CURRENCY C
ON EXTRACT(YEAR FROM S.fecha_compra) = C.YEAR
   AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM S.fecha_compra) = C.MONTH
   AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM S.fecha_compra) = C.DAY
   AND S.MONEDA = C.CURRENCY
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT MAX(year)
       , MAX(month)
       , MAX(day)
       , MAX(currency)
       , MAX(currency_value)
   FROM CURRENT_CURRENCY
   GROUP BY currency
) DT 
ON S.MONEDA = DT.CURRENCY 

Esto funciona en parte por que para los registro que coinciden con el segundo join hace el calculo tomando el maximo valor de esa moneda (|2023|5|6|MXN|0.3269|), pero ese no es le valor mas actual.

Es una solución muy especial tomar el cambio de hoy, cuando falta el cambio de una fecha. Típicamente usaremos el cambio más actual hasta esa fecha en tal situaciones (por ejemplo 2024-05-01, si falta 2024-05-02).

Luego de hacer varias pruebas logre dar con la consulta que logra obtener los resultados esperados (Valor mas actual para una moneda específica).
Lo que hice fue:

Hacer uso de la funcion ROW_NUMBER dentro de una subconsulta ordenada de manera descendente por cada uno de los valores requeridos (year, month, day).
Posteriormente  valido que el valor resultante corresponda a 1 y asi solo obtener el valor mas reciente.

SELECT
   S.*
   , CASE
       WHEN C.currency IS NULL THEN O.tarifa_base * DT.currency
       ELSE O.tarifa_base * C.currency
    END AS tarifa_base_usd
FROM
    SALES S
    LEFT JOIN CURRENT_CURRENCY C
    ON EXTRACT(DAY FROM O.fecha_compra) = C.day
        AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM O.fecha_compra) = C.month
        AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM O.fecha_compra) = C.year
        AND cur.currency = O.moneda
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    ( SELECT
                          CC.*
                        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY currency ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC, day DESC) RN
                      FROM
                          CURRENT_CURRENCY CC ) SQ
                WHERE SQ.RN = 1
                ) DT
    ON O.moneda = DT.currency


Asi se veria la consulta si mostramos los valores para cada union



id_
fecha_compra
moneda
tarifa_base
impuesto
currency_value1
currency_value2




1
2024-05-01
MXN
15000
500
0.3565
0.3269


2
2024-05-01
MXN
15000
500
0.3565
0.3269


3
2024-05-02
MXN
15000
500
NULL
0.3269


4
2024-05-02
MXN
15000
500
NULL
0.3269


5
2024-05-03
MXN
15000
500
0.3789
0.3269


6
2024-05-03
MXN
15000
500
0.3789
0.3269




Teradata tiene la cláusula QUALIFY para simplificar tu subconsulta: LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM current_currency QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY currency ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC, day DESC) = 1) dt.

Gracias por tu aporte, en verdad que lo simplifica!
